# jquery convert price from 5 decimals to round up to 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, decimal, rounding

I have a price number that looks like this: $27,272.70000

I'm trying to make it look like this: $27,272.70

I'm stuck with trying different methods but here is what i've got so far:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   jQuery('.cart-table-wrapper #shopping-cart-table tbody > tr').each(function() {

   var the_sp_subtotal = jQuery(this).find('td.col-total.a-right span.price').text().replace("$", "");

   var new_sp_subtotal = parseFloat(the_sp_subtotal).toFixed(2); 
   console.log(new_sp_subtotal);

});

});
```

But the result that I get is: 27.00

Here is the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zqe37xsk/1/

Can someone please help me, what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you

Comment: add a working snippet for this. This is too abstract.

Comment: Here is the code - https://jsfiddle.net/zqe37xsk/1/

Answer (score 0):

`parseFloat("27,272.70")` returns `27` because the `,` in `27,272.70` is no longer part of a number.

As an alternative approach you could replace the part behind the last thousands separator and call `toFixed` on that. Then you can just join everything back together.

In your `each` function, use:

```
const [dollar, ...separatedNumber] = jQuery(this).find('td.col-total.a-right span.price').text().split(/\$|,/);

separatedNumber[separatedNumber.length - 1] = Number(separatedNumber.slice(-1)).toFixed(2);

console.log("$" + separatedNumber.join(","));
```

Comment: Hmm thanks, but how do I add the thousand separator back?

Comment: @user3847953 See if my edited answer is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

To format a currency string properly you could use the [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) function. For this to properly work you have to transform your string into a float.

```js
var price = '27,272.70000';
price = parseFloat(price.replace(/[$,]/g, ""));

console.log(price.toLocaleString('us-EN', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD'
}));
```